# MVC - Display multiple Controller results in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller in my MVC sire that has a couple of methods along the lines of the following:

```
public ActionResult _GetServiceStatus()
{
...
}

public ActionResult _GetEventLogErrors()
{
...
}
```

Each of these methods references a different class type that I have stored in my Model, Service and Event respectively. These can be seen below:

```
public class Service
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string EntryType { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want to do is to show the results of these methods on a single view. I already have this working for the Services check, with the results displaying correctly, but I cannot find how to add in the Event results.

What I have currently in my view is below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Monitoring";
}

@model IEnumerable<SystemMonitoringTool.Models.Monitoring.Service>

<div style="width:25%">
    <span>
        Services
    </span>
    <table id="services" style="border:solid; border-width:2px; width:100%">
        @foreach (var item in Model) {  
         <tr>
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status)
             </td>
         </tr>                       
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Can someone help me find a way to display these side by side on the same view? Will be happy to provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use child actions. Instead of directly going to one of these individual controller actions, instead add an action like:

   ```
   public ActionResult Monitoring()
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```

   You'll notice this action doesn't do much. It's just rendering a view. Then you'll need to move your HTML for services/events into partial views. For example, `_GetServiceStatus.cshtml` and `_GetEventLogErrors.cshtml`, where the model for each will be a collection of your `Service` or `Event` types, respectively. Finally, in your `Monitoring.cshtml` view (based on the action name above), you'll add:

   ```
   @Html.Action("_GetServiceStatus")
   @Html.Action("_GetEventLogErrors")
   ```

   This view doesn't need a model, because it's not directly working with anything.
2. Use a view model that encapsulates your two collections:

   ```
   public class MonitoringViewModel
   {
       public List<Service> Services { get; set; }
       public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Then you'll still need a unifying action. But here, you'll populate both lists. Basically, you'll just be moving your two existing actions into one:

   ```
   public ActionResult Monitoring()
   {
       var model = new MonitoringViewModel
       {
           Services = /* code to retrieve services */,
           Events = /* code to retrieve events */
       }
       return View(model);
   }
   ```

   Then, you can iterate through each list independently to build your HTML:

   **Monitoring.cshtml** (again, based on the action name)

   ```
   @model Namespace.To.MonitoringViewModel

   ...

   <table id="services" style="border:solid; border-width:2px; width:100%">
       @foreach (var item in Model.Services) { // notice the change here  
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status)
            </td>
        </tr>                       
       }
   </table>
   ```

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. Went for the second option and its worked a treat!